# How do I change the default style of captions in Microsoft Word to automatically place captions above the captioned item?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm experimenting with [pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc) and the R knitr package in order to export R Markdown files to Microsoft Word. As part of the knitr/pandoc process, the final docx output copies the formats of a specified reference.docx. For example, level 1 section headers would follow the style of level 1 headings specified in the reference.docx's styles pane.

Knitr and pandoc do a pretty good job of forcing the new docx file to adhere to the specified formats in the reference.docx with the exception of figure captions: the final docx file has figure captions without numbering and they're below their respective figures.

In my reference.docx file, I have modified the caption style to do section level numbering (example: "Figure 1-1: Caption here"), and the captions are above the images in the reference.docx file. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to do this through the styles pane. It was a one-shot adjustment that doesn't change any default settings. I think that if I could change the default settings of figure captioning in the reference.docx through the styles pane, I could resolve this issue, but I cannot find any option to modify the default setting of the caption's location and prefix (example: "Figure 1-1: ").

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting or preference that controls it, but this seems to work:

- In Word, open the `Normal.dotm` template
  (normally found at `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm`)
- Insert a Figure of some sort
- Create a Caption using the wanted positioning
- Save the template
- Delete the Figure and the Caption (don't use Undo)
- Close and Save the template again
- Quit Word.

From now on you should find that this positioning is selected by default position.

Note: If Word does not let you save over the `normal.dotm` file,
save it as `normal2.dotm` in the same folder,
before deleting the figure and caption and saving it again.
After quitting Word, delete the original version of `normal.dotm` and rename
`normal2.dotm` as `normal.dotm`.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Word did not let me save the normal.dotm file so I followed the instructions in your note. I'm on Mac so I had to find the file in '~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content.localized/Templates.localized'. I didn't get any changes in default caption placement after going through each of these steps.

Comment: I'm not on the Mac, but I saw one source saying the file is found in `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/User Templates/ `.

Comment: I have the directory `~/Library/Application Support/` but I don't have a `Microsoft` folder.

Comment: Word for Mac is different from Windows. But one last try: Remove normal.dotm (copy first elsewhere), start Word which will create a new one, close Word, then redo the above procedure.